# How can I pass command-line arguments in IronPython?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, ironpython, imdbpy

I am working with IronPython and have got it working somehow. Though, there seems to be no resource on passing command-line arguments to Iron Python. How can I pass command-line arguments to a python program from my C# code?

```
setup = new ScriptRuntimeSetup();
                setup.LanguageSetups.Add(IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateLanguageSetup(null));
                runtime = new ScriptRuntime(setup);
                runtime.IO.RedirectToConsole();
                m_engine = runtime.GetEngine("IronPython");
                m_scope = m_engine.CreateScope();
                source = m_engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("search_movie.py \""+CommandTextBox.Text+"\"", SourceCodeKind.InteractiveCode);
                source.Execute(m_scope);
```

What more do I need to do here? As you can see, the name of the python file there is search_movie.py and it takes a movie-name as argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the values of sys.argv.

```
engine.Sys.argv = List.Make(args);
```

Check out http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/custom_executable.shtml for more details

Answer (score 2):

C# Code:

```
string file = @"C:\Users\M GHOUS\Source\Repos\dotnet_python\dotnet_python\test.py";
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
scope.SetVariable("var1", "data of var1");
scope.SetVariable("var2", "data of var2");
scope.SetVariable("var3", "data of var3");
engine.ExecuteFile(file, scope);
```

Python:

```
print(var1)
print(var2)
print(var3)
```