# Calling a Python script with Arguments using IronPython - "Need more than x values to unpack"

Tags: asp.net, python, ironpython

I'm using the following C# code to call a Python script using IronPython:

```
ScriptEngine scriptEngine;

var opts = new Dictionary<string, object>();
opts["Arguments"] = new[] { 
    Server.MapPath(@"~\Processing\input.7z"), // Input
    Server.MapPath(@"~\Processing\key.pem"),  // Key
    Server.MapPath(@"~\Processing\") };       // Output
        scriptEngine = Python.CreateEngine(opts);

var sp = scriptEngine.GetSearchPaths();
sp.Add(Server.MapPath(@"~\python\lib"));
scriptEngine.SetSearchPaths(sp);

var scope = scriptEngine.Runtime.ExecuteFile(Server.MapPath(@"~\python\test.py"));
```

The script takes the following arguments:

```
arg0,input,key,output = sys.argv
```

I'm getting the error "Need more than 3 values to unpack". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
arg0,input,key,output = sys.argv
```

unpacks the list of arguments in `sys.argv` into the four variables on the left. Since there are only three arguments in `sys.argv`, this fails with the error message you posted (apparently you need to manually pass in the script path for it to appear as the first element in `sys.argv`).

Try a different way of passing in command-line arguments (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949735/how-can-i-pass-command-line-arguments-in-ironpython/5992689#5992689)):

```
scriptEngine.Sys.argv = List.Make(new[] { 'input.7z', ... });
```

Alternatively, if that doesn't work, then either remove the `arg0` variable from the assignment in the Python file, or add the script's path explicitly as the first argument in C#.

Comment: Removing Arg0 fixed the issue. It seems IronPython/.NET handles the arguments differently. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `sys.argv` is set directly from the Arguments option. If you want the script name in there, you have to add it yourself.

Comment: note that newer versions of IronPython don't have `ScriptEngine.Sys`

Answer (score 2):

Well the literal meaning of that error is that `sys.argv` contains only 3 values, but you've got 4 variables there. (The error message that you'd get if you were trying to unpack 4 values into 3 variables would be "too many values to unpack".)

Why there's no `arg0` in `sys.argv`, I don't know -- I can only assume that it has something to do with the way .NET handles arguments in cases like these. Remove the `arg0` and see what happens.

Comment: I think you're right in that IronPython handles the arguments differently. I removed arg0 and it works.