# How To Pass Command Line Arguments IronPython

Tags: python, console, ironpython, argv, sharpdevelop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I pass command-line arguments in IronPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949735/how-can-i-pass-command-line-arguments-in-ironpython)

I am new to ironpython and sharpdevelop and I am trying to run the following code,

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv

print "The script is called:", script
print "Your first variable is:", first
print "Your second variable is:", second
print "Your third variable is:", third
```

How do I pass the arguments to the command line ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/) you

- *right-click* on the python *project*
- choose *Properties* in the context-menu
- choose the *Debug*-tab
- append your arguments in the *Command line arguments* field

Comment: This answer was really useful,  SharpDevelop  is a great tool

Answer (score 1):

Does [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949735/how-can-i-pass-command-line-arguments-in-ironpython) help you at all?

> You need to set the values of sys.argv.
>
> ```
> engine.Sys.argv = List.Make(args);
> ```

Comment: Not really, I don't know C# and I'm a beginner at ironpython.

Just trying to pass the arguments, where would I place this code in the code shown above?