# Python execute external Python Script in Console application

Tags: c#, python, console-application

Here is a code sample from a Console App I found [here](https://bytes.com/topic/python/insights/950783-two-ways-run-python-programs-c).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;

        Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine py = Python.CreateEngine(); // allow us to run ironpython programs
        Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptScope s = py.CreateScope(); // you need this to get the variables
        py.Execute("x = "+a+"+"+b,s); // this is your python program
        Console.WriteLine(s.GetVariable("x")); // get the variable from the python program
        Console.ReadLine(); // wait for the user to press a button
    }
```

I am using IronPython to try and execute a Python Script stored in a an external file called `GuessingGameOne.py`inside of a Console Application Window.

```
    import random   

def main():
    randomnumber = random.randint(1, 100)
    matched = False
    count = 0
    while (matched == False):
        inputnumber = input('Choose a number: ')        
        try:
            count = count+1
            inputnumber = int(inputnumber)
            if inputnumber > 0 and inputnumber < 101:
                comparenumber = inputnumber - randomnumber
                if comparenumber == 0:                
                    print("You guessed it. It took you " + str(count) + " guesses" )
                    matched = True
                elif comparenumber < 0:
                    print("Guess is too low")
                else:                
                    print("Guess is too high")
            else:
                print("Your guess must be between 1 and 100")

        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid Entry: Your guess must be a number")

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

How can I alter `Main(string[] args)` to call the script `GuessingGameOne.py` (shown above) and run it in a Console Window?

Comment: You should really try and understand what this piece of code is doing before posting a question to SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this code, but I found a similar answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30385400/5258056

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;
using IronPython.Runtime;

static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ScriptRuntimeSetup setup = Python.CreateRuntimeSetup(null);
            ScriptRuntime runtime = new ScriptRuntime(setup);
            ScriptEngine engine = Python.GetEngine(runtime);
            ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile("GuessingGameOne.py");
            ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();

            // You don't need this section, but added in case
            // you decide to use it later.
            List<String> argv = new List<String>();
            //Do some stuff and fill argv
            argv.Add("foo");
            argv.Add("bar");
            engine.GetSysModule().SetVariable("argv", argv);

            // You will need this though....
            source.Execute(scope);
        }
```

What you are not doing is specifying a file location to execute.