# No module name PIL when i call python Script from IronPython

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, ironpython

I'm new for both python and ironpython. Can you you help me how to call external python script from ironpython? I have a script file like

```
import sys

def sample():
    from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter
    img = Image.open("C:\\python\\images4.jpg")
    img.show(img)
```

My ironpython from console application.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] argsS)
        {
            var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
            dynamic scope = engine.CreateScope();
            engine.ExecuteFile(@"C:\\pythonscripts\\pythonCheckV.py",scope);
            scope.sample();
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

PIL won't currently work with IronPython because it uses a native C library.

Answer (score 0):

You Shouldn't import Libs inside a function , it's a bad practice, though i don't know much about IronPython but your Python Script should be something like this :

```
import sys
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter

def sample():
    img = Image.open("C:\\python\\images4.jpg")
    img.show(img)
```

If you still using old PIL , it's no longer maintained, You Should instal Pillow, it's the successor of PIL

Following Question May help you:

[How do I pass arguments to a Python script with IronPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30384793/how-do-i-pass-arguments-to-a-python-script-with-ironpython/30385400#30385400)

Comment: Thanks for you are response i will check and let you know.