# Passing values from c# window form to python script

Tags: python, c#, winforms, sockets, ipv4

Hello programmers of SO,

I am making a C# interface for a socketing,

The interface is made with C# but the code ressponsable for the actual socketing part is written in Python because writing that in C# Would be insanity,

i used some ironPython to execute the python code:

```
  var engine = Python.CreateEngine();

  engine.ExecuteFile(""); //directory is inside the quotes
```

but i need to pass some values (IP and all that jazz)

anyone know how?

I looked at [How do I pass arguments to a Python script with IronPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30384793/how-do-i-pass-arguments-to-a-python-script-with-ironpython) and it would be too hard to implement so dont ask if that thread answers my question please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the data as a string in some file in c sharp, and you could have a thread in python constantly looking for the information. It would know when the information has been stored in the file if a certain keyword is passed along with it. For example (if you were using a textfile with a location called location)

```
File.WriteAllText(location, IPAdress + "[IP]");
```

and here is the code for searching for it

```
foreach(string datainfo in File.ReadAllText(location).Split(Convert.ToChar("\n"))     
{
    if(datainfo.Contains("[IP]")
        datainfo.Replace("[IP]","");
    string Ip = datainfo; 
}
```

I don't know how to deal with files in python but the python equivalent of the csharp code above should work.

Comment: Thank you i had a massive migraine looking on the around internet, have a nice year.